# Detox Testing with Expo - Cannot connect to Emulator

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, detox

I'm currently building a proof-of-concept to see if we can use Detox for end-to-end testing a React Native app that's built using Expo.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md), but the tests are timing out. When I run the test in trace mode, I get the following error:

```
detox[11493] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 2) invoke: {"target":{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"EarlGrey","value":"instance"},"method":"det
ox_selectElementWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForAccessibilityID:","args":[{"type":"NSString","value":"vwGatedBackground"}]}}]}},"method":"assertWithMatcher:","args":[{"type":"Invocation","value":{"target":{"type":"Class","value":"GREYMatchers"},"method":"matcherForSufficientlyVisible","args":[]}}]}
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

That might be the reason why the test "Example should have welcome screen" has timed out.
```

Has anyone had any experience with getting this set-up running? I'm testing just for iOS and using the XCode iOS emulator.

As far as I can read, this is a community-supported integration rather being something offered officially by Detox, so it's possible that this just doesn't work, but I thought I'd check to see if anyone's had any luck with getting this set-up running?